# Incrementing a mysql value by one on click with AJAX?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm very new to AJAX and PHP. I'm trying to implement a "like" feature on a website where users can post memes. The user should be able to click a heart-shaped image to "like" next to a meme and the "likes" value for that particular meme should increase by one in the MySQL database, however, it is not doing anything.

The MySQL table is called meme_information and it has 5 columns, "name", "email", "likes", "image_path", and "id" which is the primary key and auto increments.

Below is the code for the page where all the memes are displayed. There is some html above that I left out, but it is just the navbar and sourcing in files. I am pretty sure that the "data" value in the AJAX is wrong, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to put in there.

**browse.php**

```
<?php 
include("connecttodb.php");

$files = glob("uploads/*.*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $supported_file = array(
            'gif',
            'jpg',
            'jpeg',
            'png'
    );

    $image = $files[$i];

    $path = substr($image,8);

    $q = "SELECT name, email, id FROM meme_information WHERE image_path= \"$path\"";

    $id = 0;
    $result = $link->query($q);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "Name: ". $row["name"] ."<br>";
            echo "Email: ". $row["email"] ."<br>";
            echo "Id: ". $row["id"] . "<br>";
            $id = $row["id"];
        }
    }

    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></img>';

    echo '<img onclick="myFunction()" src="heart-unclicked.png" style="width:50px;height:50px;">like</img>';

    echo
        '<script>
            function myFunction() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "update_likes.php",
                    data: {"increment_by": 1},
                    success: function() {
                        alert("works");
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("doesnt work");
                    },
                });
            }
        </script>';   
}
?>
```

I believe the part after WHERE in the SQL query is wrong. Not sure how I can get the id number from the meme that was "liked."

**update_likes.php**

```
<?php
    require('connecttodb.php');

    $q2 = "UPDATE meme_information SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE id='".$id."'";
    echo "The id is $id" . "<br>";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $q2);
    echo "<br> this is the id" . "$result";
?>
```

**connecttodb.php**

```
<?php
global $link;   

include("dbconnect.php");

$link = new mysqli($server,$user,$password,$dbname);

if ($link->connect_errno) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
} else {
    print"Connection successful.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This basicly means that it would take less than a minute for any visitor of your website to do whatever they want with your database. That includes destroying it. Considder using [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: That being said, the variable passed through your Ajax function is a POST variable. Meaning you can access it in your PHP script by calling `$_POST['increment_by'];` You can also pass the id of the meme like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might solve the issue.

```
<?php 
include("connecttodb.php");

$files = glob("uploads/*.*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $image = $files[$i];
    $supported_file = array(
            'gif',
            'jpg',
            'jpeg',
            'png'
    );

    $image = $files[$i];

    $path = substr($image,8);

    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></img>';

    $q = "SELECT name, email, id FROM meme_information WHERE image_path= \"$path\"";

    $id = 0;
    $result = $link->query($q);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "Name: ". $row["name"] ."<br>";
            echo "Email: ". $row["email"] ."<br>";
            echo "Id: ". $row["id"] . "<br>";
            $id = $row["id"];

            echo '<img onclick="myFunction('.$id.')" src="heart-unclicked.png" style="width:50px;height:50px;">like</img>';

        }
    }


    echo
        '<script>
            function myFunction(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "update_likes.php",
                    data: {"increment_by": 1,"id": id},
                    success: function() {
                        alert("works");
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("doesnt work");
                    },
                });
            }
        </script>';   
}
?>
```

update_likes.php

```
<?php
    require('connecttodb.php');
    if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $q2 = "UPDATE meme_information SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'";
    echo "The id is $id" . "<br>";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $q2);
    echo "<br> this is the id" . "$result";
}
?>
```